# Apache Camel - building Endpoint(s) using Java

Tags: java, apache-camel

As far as I got into `Apache Camel`, I understood that an `Endpoint` can be created using an `URI`.

```
from("jms:queue:myqueue").to("seda:myseda");
```

While I understand this pattern, I'm asking myself and you, is there a way to build those `URI`s using **type-safe** (or just safe) Java objects?

The usecase is obviously inside a custom `RouteBuilder`.

---

I know an `Endpoint` can also be retrieved using the `endpoint` method inherited from `BuilderSupport`

```
final SedaEndpoint seda = endpoint("seda:myseda", SedaEndpoint.class)
```

But that's just like writing the pure `String`.

Are there other ways to build `Endpoint`s?

---

`ParameterConfiguration` or `ComponentConfiguration` classes/interfaces are deprecated, but without pointing to an alternative or saying there is none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build those endpoints via plain Java with the `new` constructor, and then call the setter/getters. Its a bit cumbersome to do, and the vast majority of the Camel users use the URI style.

We have on the roadmap for Camel 3 to generate type-safe fluent builder for all the endpoints, for all the out of the box components, and provide this as a maven tooling plugin so 3rd party component developers can do this as well.

Comment: Thanks Claus. In the meantime I'd say sticking to String URIs is the way to go. Out of curiosity, would you personally say the manual construction via `new` is worth it?

Comment: No I would go for URIs - you can use property placeholders to externalize configuration. And there are plugins to tools that can do code assistance/type-safety on your endpoint URIs. And then wait for Camel 3 with fluent builders (however I think ppl may go for URIs as they can be fast/quick to use, and sometimes easier to read when the URIs are small, and its been the "standard" with Camel for 10+ years now.